# Enable Wifi or Cellular data in Lock screen to unlock Phone

Tags: wi-fi, lock-screens, huawei, ethernet

## Problem:

my Huawei P30 Pro is locked and I don't remember my passcode as I was using it with the fingerprint unlock for 2 years, which suddenly stopped working. I can prove that it is my phone, as I still have the packaging and the original purchase receipt and I can access the google find-my-phone, where it is shown and I could theoretically unlock it.

However, the wifi and cellular are unfortunately turned off, as I was conserving battery during a hike.

## Solutions tried:

I tried to connect it to my router via ethernet and USB-C to ethernet dock, which "worked": I see the <-> symbol in the display, I see the IP address in the router and I can ping it in the local network. It's still offline, as no notifications are coming through and it's offline google's find-my-phone :( Why?

I tried the safe mode menu, but no change, just the safe mode watermark.
I tried to update the EMUI via the recovery mode, it actually connects to my wifi(!) and tries to update, which fails and afterward DISABLES the damn wifi again. During the recovery mode and afterward it still does not show as online on google's find-my-phone.

There are no pull-down menus to enable wifi or cellular on this phone.

Unfortunately, I also seem to not have enabled the Huawei-app-thingy to unlock it, but wouldn't help anyway as I can not connect to the internet.
It's a bit ridiculous why none of these methods worked...

## Question:

Why does the ethernet not work and of course:
Any hope or do I have to keep trying 3 passwords per hour for the next 9 months ? :(

Reward for useful hints and thanks a lot ;)